# SQL Loader Unix - Giving error SQL Loader-500 Unable to open file (ABC_CTL.dat)

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, sql-loader

We are executing SQL loader command from shell script on RH Linux OS. The command passes both control file and data file as command line parameters. The syntax used is given below (masked sensitive data):

**sqlldr userid=$connstring control=/local/abc-1.2.3/instances/www.abc.com/apps/int/script/bin/ABC_CONTROL.ctl data=$f log=/local/abc-1.2.3/instances/www.abc.com/apps/int/script/logs/ABC.log bad=/local/abc-1.2.3/instances/www.abc.com/apps/int/script/logs/ABC.bad**

The data file name is passed as dynamic variable in a FOR loop to process multiple files. The data file extension is ***.app** and path is **/local/abc-1.2.3/instances/www.abc.com/apps/int/script/input**.

We have verified that **$f** variable is able to correctly point to data file. Also verified file permissions. We tried changing the directory paths as well.

Still script fails with below error: `**SQL Loader-500 Unable to open file (ABC_CTL.dat)**, SQL Loader-553 File not found, SQL Loader-509 System error: No such file or directory`

The same script runs with exact same syntax on another server. Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: It might help to show your script and how it is looping, and how you are verifying the `$f` value (and it's value - masked in the same way of course). I'd guess you have that set to the file name rather than the full path to the file.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. We are verifying that $f is capturing entire file path by printing its value in a log file just before calling sqlldr command. Also as I mentioned, we even tried to hard-code a single file name with full path instead of $f. It is strange that exact same script works file on existing server from which we are migrating to this new server.

Comment: Hi, perhaps try manually executing sql*loader from the file location it is being invoked (e.g. bin file), placing all your files there as well (control, data, bad, log). Next, one file at time, change to the file locations as you have identified and see what is causing this error?